# XOR cipher Pseudo-random key strength

Tags: encryption, xor, pseudo-random-generator

When implementing a XOR cipher with a pseudo-random key equal in length to the plaintext, Is there a significant difference in potential key strength between keys drawn from a pool of either 1000 or 5000 possible characters? (that is, each character in the key may be any one of up to five thousand possible characters) Or is this not likely to be a deciding factor in overall security for a simple XOR?

**Edit:**
I apologize if my original phrasing was ambiguous. I have hopefully improved it a bit.
(Character pool = A group of distinct character from which the cipher key may be generated.)

Comment: By "Character pool", do you mean each character is sampled from a set of $1000$ or $5000$ possible characters, or a key of length $1000$?

Comment: I agree, without defining "character pool" there is no answering this question. This seems to yet another scheme to create a very slow stream cipher out of a one-time pad.

Comment: As the question is, it is not possible to answer it. Could you add a definition of "character pool", and how it relates to your pseudo-random key?

Comment: I have edited my post to (hopefully) make it less ambiguous @Paŭlo.

Comment: Also, there is no known way to mathematically define the "strength" of any particular key string so your question can't be answered on this basis alone.

Comment: @William I am not looking for a mathematically perfect response, just a general idea of whether a broader character pool is LIKELY to make a stronger key. If you can think of a way I might improve my question, rather than simply stating it can't be answered, I would be grateful.

Comment: @figlesquidge I think I have answered your original question. Perhaps you would like to try again to answer my post?

Comment: @Daniel: Your question is related to the object known as a randomness extractor( see Wiki). So I think your question should evolve to something along the lines of "given two sources of weak randomness (1000,5000) and an extraction function A , is applying the function A to (1000) going to create a string of characters with more or less statistical bias than a string created by applying A to (5000).

Comment: @William Thank you for the feedback. I am afraid I neither have training in cryptography nor do I have any talent at mathematics, so I am struggling to understand your suggestion. Your patience will be greatly appreciated.

Since I cannot see how your suggestion applies to my post I must assume one of two things. 1) my knowledge is simply too limited to understand, 2) my post was poorly phrased and you have misunderstood my question. Since I can do little about the first possibility I will act on the second.

Comment: @William I have a XOR cipher. In order to create a key I take the length of the plaintext and use the Mersenne twister rng to generate a string the same length as the plaintext. The characters in the key are randomly selected from a predefined pool/table of characters. My question is, assuming all else remains equal, does having a larger pool/table of unique potential key characters increase the likely security of the key?

I am aware that the Mersenne is not cryptographically secure, but it does pass most tests for statistical randomness, which is all I need it to do.

Comment: @Daniel: How are you "randomly selecting " the predefined characters and how is this table of characters generated? If as you say you don't care that the Mersenne is not cryptographically secure, why worry about the quasi-randomness of your key?

Comment: @Daniel: The points William Hird has been making (and the fact I've been very busy with my real job!) are the reasons I've not responded to this yet. The main points are that you should be creating a bit-stream not a "character-stream". Since you're choosing to do the 2nd not the first, its hard to work out what the situation actually is.

Comment: `I am aware that the Mersenne is not cryptographically secure, but it does pass most tests for statistical randomness, which is all I need it to do.` — so you don't need any cryptographic security? After all, the Mersenne twister is based on a linear recursion. Any pseudo-random number sequence generated by a linear recursion is insecure, since from sufficiently long sub-sequence of the outputs, one can predict the rest of the outputs… which practically breaks your OTP cipher! Statistical randomness won't help you much in that case, as that randomness you've tested is merely theoretical.

Comment: Related to your tests, let me give you a simple example: a series of 'CC' bytes will pass a big part of statistical tests too, but it still is an easy to predict series of `CCC…`. The Mersenne Twister may "look" more random when looking at it, but you can trust in the fact that it's as easy to predict as the `CC` example. In other words: **statistical randomness is not automatically an indicator for cryptographic security!** Actually, this is a good example of why people say *“don't build your own crypto”* and *“rely on well-vetted algorithms”* as those are tested secure and faster too.

Comment: @William You asked "How are you "randomly selecting " the predefined characters and how is this table of characters generated?" It has to do with elements of the programming language I am using, but in general for each character I use Mersenne to get a number from 1 to 5000, then use a function to convert the number to its equivalent in an extended Unicode character table. 1-5000 is fairly arbitrary, but it works for my purposes. I could just as easily have characters from 5001-10000 but it would cause issues with my code. And I am not concerned with randomness as such, but the range of output

Comment: @e-sushi My purpose is not to create a 'secure' cipher. That has been done by people far smarter than I. I am just playing with various ciphers as something to tinker with in the programming language I use. While I am working to polish my method, I am not particularly concerned with certain week portions of the cipher. I use Mersenne because it is easy, not because it is best. In writing my code I must select a range of characters for the key. I can make the range very large, but I must change my code and methods to accommodate it. I am just trying to determine if it is theoretically worth it.

Comment: Please don't get my comments wrong… I just didn't want to let you wander off into the wrong direction. But obviously it's more a "research and recreation" thing. In that case, I can stop worrying. ;) /* Throwing in something constructive which might fit your needs: RC4 is simple to implement in several programming languages, it's light on resources, it represents a PRNG too, and even when it's broken for SSL purposes… it might be somewhat faster compared to MT while producing a longer range, and allowing a random-length key setup. Best of all: you can tune RC4 to use your own byte-range! */

Comment: @figlesquidge I am afraid I don't understand terms like "bit-stream", but if I had to guess I would say you mean I should be randomly generating the binary 1s and 0s rather than doing it as whole characters? I can see how that would be better, but in order to do that in the programming language I use I would have to dramatically complicate my code. I am limited by my skill and the boundaries of the language, and since my goal is recreational rather than practical it probably does not matter to my purpose. :)

Comment: @e-sushi Thanks for the tip! I will look into it. :)

Comment: @Daniel: Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a reasonable number of assumptions I'm going to have to make to try and answer this question. For perfect security, we require that the keystream is truely random, and never reused ([OTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad),[shannon](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol28-1949/articles/bstj28-4-656.pdf)).

I've decided to add in a short answer here: STOP! There's absolutely no need to use a reduced character set thing anyway - you can just use your random number generator to generate a random byte and then treat your plaintext as a series of bytes rather than as characters.

Now, I take it you're intending to obey the no-reuse requirement, which leaves us with the question of *what happens when my data isn't quite random enough?*
Firstly, lets try and work out what a pool of 1000 characters would mean. To run an xor-cipher, we somehow translate the string of characters into a string of bits, using one of many character encodings. There are $2^8=256$ bits in a byte, so I deduce that by *character* you mean that each character is encoded into two-bytes (which is roughly how [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) seems to work if you don't require very strange characters), meaning there are a total of $2^{16}=65536$ possible characters.

Now, how are you picking $1000$, or indeed $5000$ from them? If they're not randomly sampled from the total options, then you risk letting through some very significant information. For example, if your set is based around "common" characters then because of the way the character sets are constructed there are certain bits which are more likely to be set / not set in your collection of characters.

If you *have* managed to sample them totally randomly, then at the very least you're loosing out against a naive attack since there are only $1/5$ of the values to check.